# Codeigniter - use mysql result twice: once with all values and once with only unique values

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have all company-rows from mysql already loaded into the view for another feature on the page. Now I want an option box on top of the page that also requires all company-rows but only the unique values. Is there any way to do this in the view (like exampe below) or do I need to write a new query?

```
<select name='drop'>
    <?php foreach($companies as $company) : ?>
        <option value=''><?php echo $company->language->(UNIQUE); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no other way to get unique values no such function is available in CI there are two ways to do

1. by quering again the unique result set
2. Loop through your object and store the values in array and use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Try this one

```
$uniquearray=array();
 foreach($companies as $company) { 
  $uniquearray[] =    $company->your_index_goes_here;
 }

$unique_values = array_unique($uniquearray);

<select name='drop'>
    <?php foreach($unique_values as $company_name) : ?>
        <option value=''><?php echo $company_name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Hope it makes sense